# Java non-Heap memory maximum value missing in Java 8

Tags: java, memory-management

Java non-Heap memory maximum value is missing in Java 8. Is there any information on why it is missing? Is it not relevant anymore?

Here is the screenshot from JConsole

[image: JConsole]

I did a lot of googling, but could not find an answer. If anyone knows the answer please let us know.

The MemoryUsage.getMax() method also returns -1 for non-heap memory.

Comment: They've removed perm space; it's called meta space now.  You'll want to read up on it.  It's very important.

Comment: As @duffmo said, Permgen has been removed. DZone created a good article giving an overview of the changes -> https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Comment: I understand permgen being replaced with metaspace. But how is it affecting max value of non-heap memory?